# Linaro ARM toolchain prebuild binaries in 64 bit OS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, 32bit-64bit, toolchain, linaro

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty 64 bit machine. My OS and kernel are all 64 bit

```
 uname -a
Linux --- 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded the pre-built tool-chain binaries from Linaro as I’m working on something with Raspberry Pi, but I’m unable to compile my code because the binaries that I had downloaded were 32 bit, it is not getting recognized on my 64 bit machine.

Could anyone give me some pointers? (if i can find a 64bit pre-built tool-chain from Linaro) or any other solution that I  can deploy on my Ubuntu to workaround the problem

My error as below

```
some@somemachine:~/tools/compilers/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin$ file ./arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9.2 
./arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9.2: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

The file (yeap! its there in the directory)

```
some@somemachine:~/tools/compilers/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -v
bash: /home/some/tools/compilers/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem. I had to do little bit of googling.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

will fix the problem. This will enable 32 bit applications run normally on 64 bit machines + might have to install other *.i386 libraries

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, Linaro now provides native 64-bit versions of the tool-chain.

For example, the 14.11 release for the bare-metal ABI:

http://releases.linaro.org/14.11/components/toolchain/binaries/arm-none-eabi

http://releases.linaro.org/14.11/components/toolchain/binaries/arm-none-eabi/gcc-linaro-4.9-2014.11-x86_64_arm-eabi.tar.xz